# Not able to find "PKCS8Key" class and "sun.security.pkcs" package in my project

Tags: java, android, security

I'm trying to use **PKCS8Key** class to decode encrypted RSA key in my project. It seems like it is unable to find **PKCS8Key** class and **sun.security.pkcs** package in my project

can you please share your suggestions if you know the reason ?

My code looks as in link http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pkcs8.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that this question for years.
But please publish your code snippet beside the URL because URL reference maybe not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are not adding your library to project build path..

please make sure that you have followed the same steps:

1)copy the jar file to libs folder in android project

2)right click on the jar file inside the libs folder

3)choose buildpath > Add to Build Path

Hope it works...